# How to change the Startup "program.cs" to a Form in an XNA program

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, xna

I am making a game using XNA and I would like to create a login form using windows forms. I have created both of these however I cannot seem to change the startup object within the solution properties. When I click the scroll down it only gives me the option for 'program.cs' or 'Not set'. I know I could make 2 seperate projects and execute the XNA exe file through the login form, but the user could just execute it and bypass the login form.

Any ideas?

Comment: Been a while since i looked at XNA code, hence no attempt at an answer. But you could instantiate your form in Program.cs first and then your XNA.  Point here is, your applications entry point is the `static void Main(...)` method in Program.cs, not some form.

Comment: I have tried this however when I instantiate the form and call form.show(); the static method in program.cs continues and runs the game anyway, I cannot think of a way to stall the execution of the game.

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/42166/xna-windows-forms-how-make-them-work-together-without-making-the-trick-of-the

Comment: You need to call `Form.ShowDialog()` instead.  It will block until the form is closed.   Be sure to dispose of the form afterwards.